# How do I setup a Wifi Router using LAN that requires login to access the Internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

In our Dormitory, we have four members in a room. We share connection from a switch (LAN). Each of us is given a unique ID and password to connect to the internet. Now what will be the procedure to setup a WiFi router in this scenario?

The main broadband line will be connected to the router but since we only connect to the internet by creating a new connection and signing with user name and password, what will be procedure in case of wireless network?

How can this be setup?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly you want to replace switch with a router. So no change to the way you are logging to the internet (assuming it's via web interface). You need to only set up wireless network and if the setup is what I think it is, procedure will stay the same.

If I read the answer Hennes gave what I wrote is much more compact, but essentially the same. Why this answer is downvoted while his is accepted as the answer?

Comment: Nope , the situation is quite different here . I have router configured in my house also . But here we face some complications because of limited hour usage .

Comment: This comment made whole issue even more confusing. Did you downvoted my answer before or after you edited your question? can I have a reason for that?

Comment: i didn't downvote your answer .  and my original question remains same as the edited version . just some grammatical fix was done by the editor .

Comment: i just bumped into the question after a while because of a notification . The fact is that you were right . Because of some hardware error in the router , we weren't able to connect it in the normal way . In fact later we did manage to connect with the normal procedure . I have upvoted your answer but becuase of my reputation it may not show yet .

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you do not have direct access to the Internet but you probably have a connection via a proxy. That proxy is forbidding access until you authenticate yourself.

So in ASCII art:

```
PC1 ---- [-]
         [s]
PC2 ---- [w]
         [i]
PC3 ---  [t] ---------------- Proxy ------------ Internet
         [c]
PC4 ---- [h]
         [-]
```

When you try to reach the Internet the proxies probably hijacks your connection and redirects you to a landing page where you can enter a username and a password.  After that it remembers your IP and allows that IP access to the Internet.

Alternatively it could use some other authentication.

If this is correct and it allows one IP then adding a wireless access point complicates things. It will see the IP from the WAP and everyone on the WAP will get access.

Same diagram, with a W.A.P. added.

```
PC1 ---- [-]
         [s]
PC2 ---- [w]
         [i]
PC3 ---  [t] ---------------- Proxy ------------ Internet
         [c]
PC4 ---- [h]
         []
         [-]
WAP ---- [-]
```

PCx now uses wireless. The proxy intercepts. User X enters username/password and the 'WAP PC' gets access.  And via it everyone on Wireless!

I am going to assume that this is undesired.

You could solve that by using 4 access points and each of you only having the WPA2 password for your own access point.

---

now if the setup uses more complex authentication then you are in luck.  It might not allow you access unless you have a cookie set. Or maybe it builds a tunnel, or..... regardless. If the access barrier is smart enough to only recognize your PC then all you need is that single W.A.P.

Comment: The fact is , we get limited hours to access the internet , so we have to use our own account to login to access the internet . I guess we have to create 4 access points but will it maintain the hourly usage while not connected?

Comment: Without knowing how they remember who authenticated? No way to answer that.

Comment: I guess we should contact with our network engineer .  Many thanks for the information